# vscode vim fix-indentation with = not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am using below versions of vscode and vscode-vim extentions.

- OS: MAC OSX 13.X
- VSCode: 1.77.3
- VScodeVim: 1.25.2

Issue:

```
python_var = some_python_function(arg_a, arg_b, arg_c,
                                                    arg_d)        #  == on this line should fix the indentation.
```

This used to work earlier and it stopped working now.
Supposed to a supported feature as per VSCodeVim

[image]

Any idea if I am missing something?

TIA.

Comment: why not create an issue at the extension repo

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the "equalsprg" setting is properly configured in your
  VSCodeVim settings. This setting determines the command to use when
  you press "=" in Vim, and should be set to "indentexpr" to use Vim's
  indentation function. To do this, open your VSCode settings and
  search for "vim.equalsprg", and make sure it's set to "indentexpr".
- Try running the "indentexpr" command manually in Vim to see if it's
  working correctly. To do this, move your cursor to the line in
  question and type ":setl indentexpr?" (without the quotes) to see the
  current setting. It should show "indentexpr=v:indent" if it's set
  correctly. Then, type "=i" (without the quotes) to run the
  "indentexpr" command and fix the indentation. If this works, then the
  issue may be related to the VSCodeVim integration.